# What is relation between option adjusted duration and volatility

Tags: volatility, implied-volatility, duration

I am calculating oasd using implied vol of 15%.

What is relation between OASD vs Implied volatility  in theory for various maturities. I am running using MMD curve.

If anyone recommend any good article on this; it would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of securities are these, callable bonds, mortgage securities (and if so what kind?), other bonds?

Comment: These are Muni callable bond